# Manually Sync iCloud Drive on OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: macos, icloud, data-synchronization, shortcut

Is it possible to manually update the iCloud Drive folder on OS X?

Sometimes the folder does not update for ~10-20 minutes after establishing a good internet connection, so I'm hoping that there is a keyboard shortcut or menu action to refresh the iCloud Drive folder and download any documents made on another computer.

Google has so far proven itself useless. Thanks!